# Cryptic clue: of simian flanges

Tags: cryptic-clues

In a community poll for the Connections Online Quiz League, noted British quizzer Gareth Kingston presented the joke answer **"Flange of baboon in mining country perhaps (3, 6)"**.

My very amateur cryptic solving skills tell me that "country perhaps" is probably the definition, that a flange of "baboon" is either B or N, and that said flange goes inside a word for "mining." But I can't go any farther from that.

I thought research might shine light on some inside joke, but all I found was that "flange of baboons" is an nontraditional collective noun first used as a joke in *Not the Nine O' Clock News*, and doesn't really help.

So can anyone tell me the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> MAN DRILLS

Reasoning

> [Mandrills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandrill) are a primate once classified as baboons (although I think now they are seen to be different) and "man drills" is indicated by "in mining country, perhaps"